# Upload JSPDF File to Server JS and PHP messes up formatting

Tags: javascript, php, jspdf

I figured out how to upload to server but the issue I am now having is that the formatting gets messed up.  Well only the image really.

[Screenshot of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLSYt.png)

Upload script

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['data'])){
$data = $_POST['data'];
// print_r($data);
$filename = rand();
file_put_contents( "content/" . $filename .".pdf", $data );
} else {
echo "No Data Sent";
}
exit();
?>
```

JS

```
<script>
function userinfo() {

     var d = new Date();
     month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
     day = '' + d.getDate(),
     year = d.getFullYear();
     var n = d.getTime();
     var now = new Date();
     var months = ['JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR', 'APR', 'MAY', 'JUN', 'JUL', 'AUG', 'SEP', 'OCT', 'NOV', 'DEC'];
     var formattedDate = now.getFullYear() + months[now.getMonth()] + now.getDate();
     var name = document.getElementById('name');
     var name2 = name.innerHTML;

    var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
    source = $('.modal-body')[0];
    specialElementHandlers = {
        '#bypassme': function (element, renderer) {
            return true
        }
    };
    margins = {
        top: 80,
        bottom: 60,
        left: 40,
        width: 522
    };

    pdf.fromHTML(
    source, // HTML string or DOM elem ref.
    margins.left, // x coord
    margins.top, { // y coord
        'width': margins.width, // max width of content on PDF
        'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    },

    function (dispose) {
        pdf.save(name2 + ' Login Information.pdf');
        var pdf2 = pdf.output();

          $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "upload.php",
            data: {data: pdf2},
          }).done(function(data){
             console.log(data);
          });

    }, margins)


    ;}
</script>
```

As you can see from the image the top left logo is all garbled.  <= is that a word :)

It should be our company logo and in color.

Comment: Can you see the AJAX call being executed in the Network tool? That would be the first step towards debugging

Comment: @ADyson I sure can.  Its a 200 and in the header it has the inforation of the pdf file.

Comment: @ADyson I figured out my original issue but ran into another.  I edited this post.